Backup Directory Path Ola Maintenance Script: platform agnostic path on Windows q:/backup/folder
We are using configuration management, specifically Chef, to install SQL server on many new VMs. Part of the cookbook specifies the default SQL directories including the backup directory. In order to be platform agnostic the paths are specified with forward slashes instead of windows specific backslashes. This works and backups through the context menu in SSMS can parse the path and execute a backup.
The issue is that we are using the Ola Hallengren Maintenance solution for backups and the directory check block specifically disallows /%/% path unless on Linux.
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Directories WHERE Mirror = 0 AND (NOT (DirectoryPath LIKE '_:' OR DirectoryPath LIKE '_:\%' OR DirectoryPath LIKE '\\%\%' OR (DirectoryPath LIKE '/%/%' AND @HostPlatform = 'Linux') OR DirectoryPath = 'NUL') OR DirectoryPath IS NULL OR LEFT(DirectoryPath,1) = ' ' OR RIGHT(DirectoryPath,1) = ' '))
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Errors ([Message], Severity, [State])
    SELECT 'The value for the parameter @Directory is not supported.', 16, 1
  END

Has anyone encountered this, is there a reason for the OR (DirectoryPath LIKE '/%/%' AND @HostPlatform = 'Linux') guard unless on Linux? Looking for solutions outside of rewriting the configuration management cookbook.

According to https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/14, MSSQL's Backup and Restore commands have problems with forward slashes. That thread is from 2017, so the MSSQL problem might have been fixed, but Ola's scripts might still need to account for it.
